# Draw the item after decoding the instructions

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, visual

Draw the missing item replacing the question mark
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- 4 is partly covered by 0
- 0 is completly covered by 3
- 6 is partly covered by 0
- 6 is partly uncovered by 0
- 4 is completely uncovered by 6
- 4 is partly uncovered by 3
- 6 is not covered by 4

So we need a figure that

- 6 is partly covered by 4
- 3 is completely uncovered by 6
- 0 is partly covered by 3
- 4 is completely covered by 0
- 0 is partly covered by 6
- 4 is partly covered by 3
- 6 is completely covered by 0

Therefore,

> [image]

Comment: Awesome graphics! Mind if I ask what tool did you use?

Comment: I used Keynote for OS X. It's very handy for drawing vector graphics :-)